# Loading a record into ember-data creates a nearly empty record

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

So while writing an Ember.js app, I couldn't get the most basic ember-data records to work. Using the latest git builds of Ember.js and ember-data, I ran this code in firebug: (Using what I learned from the guide to ember-data on github)

```
App.store = DS.Store.create({
    revision: 8,
    adapter: DS.RESTAdapter.create({bulkCommit: false, namespace: "api"})
});

App.Test = DS.Model.extend({
    test: DS.attr('string')
});

App.store.load(App.Test, 1, {test: "abc"});

App.store.findById(App.Test, 1);
```

**Edit: mspisars' answer made me realize that findById() is not the function to use** (Although it does have the same result). That's a function for internal ember-data use.

The last line returns an App.Test object with its test property set to "undefined".  I got the same results using createRecord to create the record (admittedly I don't remember the difference).

From what I can see this is not a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10721637/ember-data-only-populating-the-id-property) question, although the symptoms are almost the same.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I'm unable to duplicate this problem. What version of ember-data are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was accessing the stored data in the wrong way. After loading the data, I was trying to get the data like this:

```
t = App.store.find(App.Test, 1);

console.log(t.test); // wrong
```

That returns *undefined*.

I should have done this:

```
console.log(t.get('test'));
"abc"
```

Answer (score 0):

Is findById a method you created? I do not see it anywhere in ember-data master!
Try App.Test.find("1") or App.store.find(App.Test, "1")

Comment: It looks like findById isn't the right function to use (It's "private"). Even so, the others still don't work.